# Parse Server on Azure Managed Services

Tags: azure, parse-platform, parse-server

I'm trying to set up a Parse Server on Azure Managed Services, but it asks for certain information that I'm not aware of. Also how do you ultimately connect your app to this from Parse ?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you want to edit your question, to call out *which* things you aren't aware of?

Comment: This link looks really helpful! https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-the-publication-of-parse-server-with-azure-managed-services/

Comment: It was "Resource Group" in particular and "Parse Server Name" (which I assume is some name you just give to recognize the instance)